# InvalidOperationException within BeginInvoke

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, multithreading, begininvoke

I am getting an `InvalidOperationException` with message `Cross-thread operation not valid..`

The `_waitForm` is created in the constructor of the main form. The method in the screenshot gets called from another thread. I though this is what `BeginInvoke` solves. I know that I am accessing the form from another thread than the one created.
Any ideas on how to solve this?

[image]

Here is the stacktrace:

```
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Handle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_ContainsFocus()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SelectNextIfFocused()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Hide()
   at YYYYYY.Boundary.ZzzzzForm.<HideWaitForm>b__c() in R:\Projects\XXXX\trunk\src\YYYYYY\Boundary\ZzzzzForm.cs:line 514
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackDo(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackHelper(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallback(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbacks()
```

*sorry for the screenshot, I wanted to show the whole picture*

Comment: If you want to wait for the invocation to finish, you should just call the synchronous `Invoke()`.

Comment: Do you have two UI threads?

Comment: There is only one UI thread ( like all classic winforms appls)

Comment: @SLaks I've added the stacktrace

Comment: Consder naming your GUI thread so that you can verify it's what's creating the form and executing the UI code. The snapshot that I see in the question here looks correct at first glance, so I suspect that something unexpected is happening elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to operate on `_waitForm` through:

```
_waitForm.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(_waitForm.Hide));
```

Alternatively, if the above doesn't work:

```
_waitForm.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => 
{
    _waitForm.Reset();
    _waitForm.Hide();
}));
```

Comment: Yes. You should invoke a code that operates the control with the dispatcher of this control.

Comment: This causes a deadlock. If I use instead Begin/End Invoke the EndInvoke blocks execution

Answer (score 0):

I've found it. Of course it was my mistake!

The opposite of that method is the one showing the `_waitForm`. I had mistakenly called `_waitForm.Show()` from another than the UI thread without invokation. Strangely, this was able to succeed and caused this exception (that has the wrong message).